# How can I determine the best thicknesses of a circular plate to achieve minimum weight and high strength?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, finite-element-method, cad, simulation

[image]

I want to design a circular plate made from iron ductile material, So I want to determine the best thicknesses of the profile (t1,t2,t3,...etc) as shown in the image tyo achieve the best plate weight and minimum plate deflection at point t6.

Comment: add ribs or bands.

Comment: I added that already but I want a mathematicl method to determine these thicknesses

Comment: What is the load and how is the plate supported?

Comment: the load is pressure and the plate is supported from 2 sides

Comment: @AhmedObaid If the plate is circular, how does it have 2 ends? It seems like a pressure vessel "flat" end to me. Where is the axis? You are leaving a lot of important details which are needed for a proper answer.